# Which one is better to represent an API fetched data in react js and please explain how to do that?

Tags: reactjs, api, highcharts, linechart, alpha-vantage

I am trying to represent the array of values to a line chart with reactJS by fetching the data from the API and the result would be somewhat similar like below

The output will be as below

```
0: (2) ["2019-12-10 16:00", "151.3895"]
1: (2) ["2019-12-10 15:45", "151.4298"]
```

Is it possible to use high-charts with react to map the array into a line chart? Please guide me to map this array-like timestamp in the x-axis and the value in Y-axis

Answer (score 0):

First of all - the y value in data array ([x, y]) must be a number format, not string. Next, you need to set xAxis.type to 'category' to represent those x string values on the chart.

```
this.state = {
  options: {
    xAxis: {
      type: "category"
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: fetchedData
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-1666y
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

If you have any additional question - feel free to ask!